# JQuery Fade In Attr Change

Tags: jquery, fadein

I was wondering if it was possible to add a fadeIn effect when an attr is changed for example I have this code working, when the user clicks on img2 imgmain's src is changed to img2's like this:

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
  $("#imgmain").attr("src","img1.jpg");
  });

  $('#img2').click(function() {
  $("#imgmain").attr("src","img2.jpg"); }

  );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just call the fadeIn method in the click handler code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change it on the `fadeOut()` callback, like this:

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
  $("#imgmain").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","img1.jpg").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks . it works but can it be improoved? because there is white screen showing up when loading next image

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
  $("#imgmain").fadeOut(function(){
  $(this).attr("src","img1.jpg");
  $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

or...!

```
$('#MRMBIG').fadeOut('slow').attr('src',imgsrcclickshode).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the this keyword along with src, you don't have to iterate the image's source.  For example

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
  var thisImage = this.src;
  $("#imgmain").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src",thisImage).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Better yet, you should give these images a classname also, this way it applies to them all.  The above code will only work for the first image, while the code below, assuming they all have a class of thumb, will let you specify all of them

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
  var thisImage = this.src;
  $("#imgmain").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src",thisImage).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have redundancy in your code. Better:

```
$('#img1, #img2').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $("#imgmain").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", src).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Usually, when you have multiple items, you use the class selector instead of listing the IDs of the items:

`$(".images").click(` ...